# Synchronisation SQL Server Compact 3.5 in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, sql-server-ce-3.5

In my project, I want to sync SQL Server Compact 3.5 with MSSQL Server 2008. I passed all steps in Visual Studio 2010 like adding New Item >> Local Database Cache >> Configure Data Synchronization etc. The connection was completed successfully. But after this stage, I don't know how can i do synchronization. 
I have a button named "Check Updates". When click the update button, synchronization must start and new data from the MSSQL Server must be added to "data.sdf". I have no idea about how to do this. I am a beginner in C#. Could you help me?
Kind regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examine this link. It shows how to use the Sync Framework 2.1 database providers to configure and execute synchronization between a SQL Server database and one or more SQL Server Compact databases.
 http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-SQL-Server-de6c8ff8

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at the tutorials for the microsoft sync framework?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928606.aspx

that one deals with executing synchronization.
or in general
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494.aspx

maybe not quite a beginners guide but it's a place to start

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be easier. But it is quite hard. I am searching if whether there is a simpler way.

Comment: @user1723204 - the links you posted uses providers that doesnt work with the codes generated by the Local Database Cache project item.

Answer (score 0):

the Local Database Cache project item would have generated all the code for you and you just have to invoke it.

see: [Walkthrough: Extending the Local Database Cache to Support Bidirectional Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc761546.aspx) for the part that invokes the sync.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this utility already written to sync the data between SQL server and SQL Compact but it currently support only SQL 2000 and 2005

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25685/SQL-Server-to-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-Database